# Get values from JSON - SQL Server

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server, json-query

I have the following `JSON`:

```
[
  {
    "email_id": 1598819368,
    "email": "test01@abc.net"
  },
  {
    "email_id": 1598819369,
    "email": "test02@abc.net"
  },
  {
    "email_id": 1598819370,
    "email": "test03@abc.net"
  },
  {
    "email_id": 1598819371,
    "email": "test04@abc.net"
  }
]
```

How do I return a list of just the email addresses using SQLServer 2017?

```
-------------------
   emailaddress   
-------------------
  test01@abc.net
  test02@abc.net
  test03@abc.net
  test04@abc.net
```

I've been trying to use `JSON_VALUE` or `JSON_QUERY` but I either only get one email address or NULLs.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
declare @json         nvarchar(max)=N'[
  {
    "email_id": 1598819368,
    "email": "test01@abc.net"
  },
  {
    "email_id": 1598819369,
    "email": "test02@abc.net"
  },
  {
    "email_id": 1598819370,
    "email": "test03@abc.net"
  },
  {
    "email_id": 1598819371,
    "email": "test04@abc.net"
  }
]'

select email from openjson(@json) with (email_id            bigint,
                                        email               nvarchar(200));
```

Results

```
email
test01@abc.net
test02@abc.net
test03@abc.net
test04@abc.net
```